# Using JQuery or JS to add classes to raw unformatted html text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to format the returned text from an API call, however what is being returned is poorly formatted and does not have css elements. Additionally, the only html element is a "< br >< br >" to break up the body content (had to add the spaces to display on screen).

What I am trying to do is assign a class when each 
 is detected.

I am however struggling.

What I have so far.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {


    $('.text-wrapper').each(function(){

     if ( $(this).is("<br><br>") )
      {
           $(this).addClass("newclass");
      }

    })

   });
</script>
```

Example of the layout that I am working with.

```
<div class = "text-wrapper">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. <br><br> Vivamus pharetra at justo ut rhoncus. Suspendisse potenti. Morbi accumsan felis in mi aliquet, vitae efficitur nulla consectetur. Praesent in ante id purus consectetur maximus in et erat. <br><br> In eget augue ut tortor iaculis rutrum ultrices et nulla. In euismod ultrices erat, a bibendum metus egestas eget. Morbi eu viverra mauris, ut finibus velit. Etiam at erat rhoncus, porta ante non, placerat nibh. <br><br> Aenean eget lacus vitae neque fermentum pulvinar ut a mi.
</div>
```

I am aiming to have a structure similar to the following as a starting point.

```
<div class = "text-wrapper">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. <div class="newclass">Vivamus pharetra at justo ut rhoncus. Suspendisse potenti. Morbi accumsan felis in mi aliquet, vitae efficitur nulla consectetur. Praesent in ante id purus consectetur maximus in et erat.</div><div class="newclass">In eget augue ut tortor iaculis rutrum ultrices et nulla. In euismod ultrices erat, a bibendum metus egestas eget. Morbi eu viverra mauris, ut finibus velit. Etiam at erat rhoncus, porta ante non, placerat nibh. </div><div class="newclass"> Aenean eget lacus vitae neque fermentum pulvinar ut a mi.</div>
</div>
```

JS and JQuery is still very much new to me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you have some unwanted double  line breaks that you want to replace and convert paragraphs or sections to divs.

I might do something like get the text inside your text wrapper did. Then use Javascript string.split function to to remove the  
  and convert those paragraphs into arrays then add a new div  with class and replace it back into the main textwrapper div with $.html

like this :

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function () {

   var before=$(".text-wrapper").html() // get text into variable

   var textArr=before.split("<br><br>")  // create an array from your text and split it up by the unwanted words which will get removed as well

   var newDivsArr=[]
   $.each( textArr, function(i,val){            
        var newDiv=document.createElement("div") // create new element
        $(newDiv).addClass("newclass")  // add class
        $(newDiv).html(val) // add text paragraph to new divs htmlcontents
        newDivsArr.push(newDiv) // add new div to an array of divs before looping back through the rest 

   })

   $(".text-wrapper").html(newDivsArr) // update your main div with new set of arrays 
 }
</script>
```

Comment: You could simplify this method to `$('.text-wrapper').each(function() { this.innerHTML = '<div class="newclass">' + this.innerHTML.split('<br><br>').join('</div><div class="newclass">') + '</div>'; });`, which removes the need to store and mutate variables. But I would still recommend the `.replace()` method shown in my answer because ) it uses only one function call rather than two ) it doesn't coerce a string into an array back to a string again.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap the poorly formated html in `<div class="newclass"></div>` and then replace `<br><br>` with `</div><div class="newclass">`, which will result in properly formatted html.

```
$('.text-wrapper').each(function() {
  this.innerHTML = `
    <div class="newclass">
      ${this.innerHTML.replace(/<br><br>/g, '</div><div class="newclass">')}
    </div>`;
});
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions